# Await sql and push to array before executing the result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I'm using *mysql* npm package to get data from the database.
My goal is to add every `list`(id) from `lists` Table and push it into `lists` array.
I'm getting the correct data from the database but when I `result` the query `lists` array is empty.

I think that I have to add `async` and `await` to the code to make it work. Tried in several places but I didn't make it work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
// GET - get all grocery_lists
Grocery_list.getAll = (result) => {
  let lists = []; // <--- List Array

  sql.query("SELECT id FROM lists", (err, res) => { // <--- Get all id from 'lists' table
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    res.forEach(list => { // <--- Loop thru all lists
      sql.query(`
        SELECT items.id, items.name, items_x_lists.purchased
        FROM items_x_lists
        INNER JOIN items ON items_x_lists.itemId = items.id
        WHERE items_x_lists.listId = ${list.id};
      `, (err, res) => { // <--- Get all items for ${list.id}  from 'items' table
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        const list = {};
        list.id = res.id;

        console.log(list); // <--- { id: 1 } ... { id: 2 }
        lists.push(list);


      });
    });
    result(null, lists); // <--- returning empty array instead of [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it simply like this (not the exact code) but I think you've got the idea:

```
// GET - get all grocery_lists
Grocery_list.getAll = (result) => {
  getData().then(data => {
    // call result(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    // handle error for no data or any other errors
  })
}

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    var res = await sql.query("SELECT id FROM lists");
    // Handle error if no data found
    if (!res) { Promise.reject("No data found"); }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  const listIds = res.map(id => id);  // array of ids

  try {
    var data = await sql.query(`
        SELECT items.id, items.name, items_x_lists.purchased
        FROM items_x_lists
        INNER JOIN items ON items_x_lists.itemId = items.id
        WHERE items_x_lists.listId in ${listIds};`);
    // Handle error if no data found
    if (!data) { return Promise.reject("No data found") }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  return Promise.resolve(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this mighht be the solution

```js
Grocery_list.getAll = async (result) => { return sql.query("SELECT id FROM lists", (err, res) => { // <--- Get all id from 'lists' table if (err) { console.log(err); } }); };
```

Comment: Did not work. I'm pretty sure that you just `async` is not making any difference if you don't `await` any code.

Comment: Grocery_list.getAll = async (result) => {
 

 return sql.query("SELECT id FROM lists", (err, res) => { // <--- Get all id from 'lists' table
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  });
};

Comment: async awaits on return try this maybe to pace return on sql.query

Comment: if even this doesnt work try placing await where return was

Answer (score 0):

I’m outside, so I can only edit with my mobile phone. If the layout is strange, I apologize for it.

First of all, if it is me, I will adjust a few places

1.Create an async function and use Promise.all technology

```
async function queryAll(querys){
  return await Promise.all(querys);
}
```

2.Create a Promise function to execute each sql

```
const queryPromise = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.query(
      'SELECT items.id, items.name, items_x_lists.purchased FROM items_x_lists INNER JOIN items ON items_x_lists.itemId = items.id WHERE items_x_lists.listId = ? ;',
      id,
      (err, rows, fields) => {
        console.log(rows);
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(rows);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

3.Adjust the internal logic of the getAll event

```
const querys = []
res.forEach(list => {
  querys.push(queryPromise(list.id));
});
const querysResults = await queryAll(querys);// remember to use async for function
querysResults.forEach(querysResult => {
  lists.push({id:querysResult['id']});
});
```

Because there is no computer on hand, there may be some situations that need to be judged, but roughly this will work normally.

Hope this helps you :)